# How to return value of userPass from array of object using angular 7?

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular-components

How to access value of userPass from array of object using angular 7?

I need to access Property userPass value from array of object

I have variable type any his name auth

auth have array of object

I need to access property value of userpass from json below

```
var auth;
auth =  


    [{"userLoginID":0,"userName":"test","userMail":"ahmedsa.aziz.ba@gmail.com","userPass":"12345678","fkTeamID":0  

    ,"isAdmin":false,"createdBy":0,"createdDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","isHidden":false}]
```

I need to access userPass value meaning i need to access 12345678

what i try is

```
ngOnInit() {


     auth.forEach(element => {
      element.forEach(au => {
         console.log(au.userPass);

      });
      });
     userpathvalue=???
      }
```

Meaning i need to access value 12345678

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing field value in array of objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183659/accessing-field-value-in-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: You have a single array. Why would you need two loops? auth[0].userPass is the userPass of the first object in the array. If you want to access the userPass of every element, use a loop: auth.forEach(element => console.log(element.userPass))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since length of your array is one, so then this code is enough to get value.

`auth[0].userPass`

So, If you do :

`console.log(auth[0].userPass)`

It will print **"12345678"**

***Note: This solution is only for your specific case because you have the length of your array is one, if more then you have to loop through.**